# What is the difference in meaning between purge and cleanse?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What is the difference between purge and cleanse?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**[purge](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/purge)**" mostly speaks about "*removing something entirely*" or "*getting rid of something completely*" whereas "**[cleanse](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cleanse)**" speaks about "*removing something bad, harmful or unpleasant from something*" or "*making something pure*", or even "*making something clean*". Depending on the understanding of the words "**pure**" and "**clean**" we can assume that it means remove almost entirely.

There are some cases and scenarios where they can't be interchangeable.

I often compare "**purge**" to "*eradicate*" and "**cleanse**" to "*purify*".
But in English a word can have very different meanings in various contexts.

Comment: There are contexts in which they are certainly not interchangeable. And their connotations are not interchangeable. Example: A face wash ad will steer far clear of "purge" but not "cleanse".

Comment: Besides, "to purge" has the meaning of "to free from sin or guilt" which hardly applies to "cleanse"

Comment: "I often compare "purge" to "eradicate"" Yes, in "Stalin’s purges of Soviet officials" they mean almost the same thing:-) but it doesn't stand near to "make clean" used literally. No?

Comment: @Rompey well, much depends on the context. English is entirely context-based.